# An exercise in Conway’s functional analysis, Page 25, exercise 2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a measurable space, let $u_1, u_2$ be sigma-finite measures defined on $X $. Put $u=u_1+u_2$. Show that the map $$V : L^2(u) \to L^2(u_1)+L^2(u_2)$$ defined by $Vf=f_1+f_2$, where $f_j$ is the equivalence class of $L^2(u_j)$ corresponding to $f$, is well-defined, linear and injective.
> Show that $V$ is an isomorphism iff $u_1, u_2$ are mutually singular.

I have shown $V$ is well-defined, linear, and injective. But I don’t know how to show the 'iff' part of the exercise. Can anyone give me some solutions or hint?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Can you show that $V$ is surjective if $u_1,u_2$ are mutually singular? This shouldn't be too hard: take an element in the codomain: there is an obvious way to make an element with it that might live in $L^2(u)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but it is not so obvious for me. Cou you show me in detail ? Thanks again !

Comment: By definition, an element in the codomain is of the form $(f_1, f_2)$ with $f_i \in L^2(u_i)$. With $f_1$ and $f_2$, how would you make an element in $L^2(\mu)$? Just think very naive.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.